# How an Android App developer should send me the USERPWD to my PHP API?

Tags: php, android

This is my first time doing an API and I have set a token that the client must send to me to access the API content.

So my way to retrieve this token is:

```
$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']
```

But the App developer keep saying that he can not find the way to send this info so my API can not recognize it.

Any idea how should he send me? or maybe `$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']` is not the right way to retrieve the token?

Comment: it  wont be a `$_SERVER` variable your after, But  what it will be is going to depend on things you have yet to show us

Comment: I want them to send the token in the header and then retrieve it on my side

Comment: `getallheaders` or `apache_response_headers` by the sounds of it. or you could just use POST

Answer (score 0):

We can pass the token to retrieve as `$headers['Authorization']`. To set this variable from Android we need to following.

```
String credentials = username + ":" + password;
String basicAuth = "Basic " + new String(new Base64().encode(credentials.getBytes()));
HttpURLConnection myURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)myURL.openConnection();
myURLConnection.setRequestProperty ("Authorization", basicAuth);
```

To check if client has sent token or not, You can do it like follow:

```
if(isset($headers['Authorization'])){
    $api_key=$headers['Authorization'];
}
```

This is called Basic Authorization, It's not as secure as [OAuth2.0](http://oauth.net/2/). If you need solid security try to change your current code to **OAuth2.0** and for normal scenario **Basic Auth** should work.

Answer (score 0):

This example adds several parameters to the post request :

```
String url = "https://www.example.com/api.php";

HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);

// add header
post.setHeader("USERPWD", USERPWD_VALUE);

List<NameValuePair> urlParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("locale", ""));
urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("caller", ""));

post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(urlParameters));

HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
System.out.println("Response Code : " 
            + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
```

I think this will resolve you problem.

Answer (score -1):

you need to do the following

1. send request from mobile app into endpoint resource [php]
2. php generate access token for your app and return response to mobile .
3. mobile app use this token with every request to determine if it's authorize to  call this resource or not .
4. you can check example of previous comments from this github url:
   https://github.com/lucadegasperi/oauth2-server-laravel